# SSL Connection Error in Xcode 4.4 when validating app upload

Tags: iphone, ssl, upload, itunes, xcode4.4

I cannot upload apps to itunes via the application loader of Xcode Organiser.  during validation I receive a 'SSL Connection Error during validation and the upload fails.

I've tried, reset safari, reboot.  restart router.  Now I'm stumped.

I know my ISP recently upgraded my broadband link and it is supposed to be going through a stabilising period.  but i cannot upload files of any size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is not being caused by Xcode.  It was my broadband network dropping packets on uploads.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Xcode works for me. I also heard people restarting their WiFi.